# SwiftUI Picker Label with PickerStyle .menu in iOS HowTo

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, picker

For some reason Apple decided to drop Label support for Pickers
(tested in iOS15 and iOS16)

For example:

```swift
Picker(selection: $gender,
                   label:
                    "Select your gender"
                   , content: {
                            Text(Gender.male.rawValue).tag(Gender.male)
                            Text(Gender.female.rawValue).tag(Gender.female)
                            Text(Gender.nobinary.rawValue).tag(Gender.nobinary)
            }).pickerStyle(.automatic)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .accentColor(.white)
```

ignores the label view.

[image]

So howto solve that?

Answer (score 16):

To add a Label View out of the box without custom View one has to use Picker in Menu View embedded.
Now one can use modifier on the Menu Label Views and even use logic for the selected text.

```swift
Menu {
    Picker(selection: $gender,
        label: EmptyView(),
        content: {
            Text(Gender.male.rawValue).tag(Gender.male)
            Text(Gender.female.rawValue).tag(Gender.female)
            Text(Gender.nobinary.rawValue).tag(Gender.nobinary)
        }).pickerStyle(.automatic)
           .accentColor(.white)
    } label: {
        Text(gender == .unselected ? "Select your gender" : gender.rawValue)
            .font(.title3)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 55)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .accentColor(.pink)
}
```

[image]